# minikube pod ip and pod cidr

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I setup minikube on my MAC.

```
~ $ kubectl describe node minikube

Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.64.2
  Hostname:    minikube
PodCIDR:                      10.244.0.0/24
PodCIDRs:                     10.244.0.0/24

~ $ kubectl describe pod mongo-depl-5fd6b7d4b4-2kprw
Name:         mongo-depl-5fd6b7d4b4-2kprw
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         minikube/192.168.64.2
Start Time:   Sun, 20 Jun 2021 15:59:05 +0800
Labels:       app=mongo-depl
              pod-template-hash=5fd6b7d4b4
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           172.17.0.4
IPs:
  IP:           172.17.0.4
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/mongo-depl-5fd6b7d4b4
```

why the pod ip 172.17.0.4 is not in the POD CIDR subnet 10.244.0.0/24?